# Multi-Color changing button using javascript in a pdf

Tags: javascript, button, colors

I can't seem to get any further with this.  I'm more of a graphics guy than a programmer.
I need a button to cycle from white to grey to red to black to white again each time the button is pressed.  There will be over one hundred of these buttons in one pdf file.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
if (this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",1,1,1])
  {
  app.alert({ cMsg: "Switch to Grey", });
  this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",.5,.5,.5];
  };

if (this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",.5,.5,.5])
  {
  app.alert({ cMsg: "Switch to Red", });
  this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",1,0,0];
  };

if (this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",1,0,0])
  {
  app.alert({ cMsg: "Switch to Black", });
  this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",0,0,0];
  };

if (this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",0,0,0])
  {
  app.alert({ cMsg: "Switch to White", });
  this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",1,1,1];
  };
```

Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: You should probably use `if ... else if ... else` instead here. Otherwise I see each of this `if` clauses implementing (as they'll check the changed value).

Comment: when you compare two values you don't use = alone. You use == or === because = means you assign the value to a variable for example.

Comment: @user2446117 what's up? Were you able to finally get a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Using your own code it would look like this:

```
if (this.getField("Button1").fillColor == ["RGB",1,1,1])
 {
  app.alert({ cMsg: "Switch to Grey", });
  this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",.5,.5,.5];
 }
else if (this.getField("Button1").fillColor == ["RGB",.5,.5,.5])
{
 app.alert({ cMsg: "Switch to Red", });
 this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",1,0,0];
}
else if (this.getField("Button1").fillColor == ["RGB",1,0,0])
{
 app.alert({ cMsg: "Switch to Black", });
 this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",0,0,0];
}
else if (this.getField("Button1").fillColor == ["RGB",0,0,0])
{
 app.alert({ cMsg: "Switch to White", });
 this.getField("Button1").fillColor = ["RGB",1,1,1];
}
```

**My Previous answer below**: (Use as reference only)

This one below is purely for JavaScript and HTML and not PDF but you will get an insight how it is done.

You could use `getElementById` and  `rgb` in JavaScript like:

```
  document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor == "rgb(0, 255, 0)"
```

I will give an example here. Let's say you have a blue colored button like

```
<div>
<button id="button1" onclick="getcolor()" style="background-color:#0000FF; padding:5px;">Colored Button - Blue</button>
</div>
```

And we want to change it to green color and if it is a green color we want to change it to blue color, so then you will have a JavaScript like this:

```
function getcolor()
{
  var button_color = document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor;
  if (button_color == "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
  {
    alert("Switch color to Grey");
    document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(128, 128, 128)";
 }
 else if (button_color == "rgb(128, 128, 128)")
 {
    alert("Switch color to Red");
    document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";       
 }
 else if (button_color == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
 {
     alert("Switch color to Black");
     document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";       
 }
 else if (button_color == "rgb(0, 0, 0)")
 {
     alert("Switch color to White");
     document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";       
 }
}
```

By the way be careful with spaces in rgb when comparing for example for blue color when comparing it should not be rgb(0,0,255) which has no space after each decimal values of the color like:

```
 if (button_color == "rgb(0,0,255)")
```

But it should be like:

```
 if (button_color == "rgb(0, 0, 255)")
```

See my [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ua4qf/3/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in a pdf file...  Anything else I need to add?